# Selenium IDE - gotoIf storeAlertPresent is false

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'll do my best to explain my issue thoroughly and clearly.

I'm testing an insurance policy admin system, where I'm entering policy holder information. I'm using a custom extension that creates random people. Part of the information that is created is a vehicle VIN. The VINs are being pulled from Polk verified VINs stored in the extension. The system I'm writing the script for has an alert if the VIN is present on another policy (not the one the script is creating). I don't want errors or the script to fail due to the alert.

verifyAlert | glob:This vehicle exists on policy:* |

This works fine when the alert IS present, but creates an error if it is NOT. It doesn't stop the script from finishing, but the 'error' in the log makes it appear to have an error when it really didn't, which results in me having to re-run the test.

storeAlertPresent | isAlert | 
gotoIf | storedVars['isAlert'] == false | skipAlert 
verifyAler | glob:This vehicle exists on policy:* | 
label | skipAlert |

This works to skip the verifyAlert when the alert isn't present, but it causes a complete failure (stops the script) when there IS an alert, because of an 'Unexpected Alert' error in the log when it hit's the gotoIf command. I have researched this most of the day and have not found any solutions that fit my needs.

Does anyone know how I can skip the alert steps if ${isAlert} is false?

Please respond with Selenium IDE solutions, as that is how the company I work for chooses to run our automated testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
verifyNotNull | isAlert|
gotoxx
storeAlertPresent | isAlert|
```

verifyNotNull will check if the entry is not null it will go to next line else it will give the error and go to next line.
where as assert stops the execution if there is any error.

hope this answer would help you!